# what is the Time complexity of redis del command?

Tags: redis

the offical document about del command:

> Time complexity: O(N) where N is the number of keys that will be removed. When a key to remove holds a value other than a string, the individual complexity for this key is O(M) where M is the number of elements in the list, set, sorted set or hash. Removing a single key that holds a string value is O(1).

why? I think even if  the key refers to a complex type, the Time complexity of del should  always is  O(1) 。  the redis db find the hash value of the key and remove it，which operation Time complexity is O(1)。

in the redis souce code,the implement of "del command" is as follow:

```
void delCommand(client *c) {
    int deleted = 0, j;

    for (j = 1; j < c->argc; j++) {
        expireIfNeeded(c->db,c->argv[j]);
        if (dbDelete(c->db,c->argv[j])) {
            signalModifiedKey(c->db,c->argv[j]);
            notifyKeyspaceEvent(NOTIFY_GENERIC,
                "del",c->argv[j],c->db->id);
            server.dirty++;
            deleted++;
        }
    }
    addReplyLongLong(c,deleted);
}
```

as above,deleting 1 key should has a complexity of O(1),regardless of a complex type。

Comment: This question is fine, it really means 'Why is the complexity of DEL listed as O(n) when the key is a complex data structure". I also wish it were O(1), sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

deleting 1 key has a complexity of O(1). deleting 5keys, has a complexity of O(5) (as it says in the documentation -> O(N) ). But if the key refers to a complex type, like a list, Redis needs to delete everything within that list as well, not just the key refering to the list. If it would just delete the key, the list would still be using memory.

a list, hash, set, etc. in Redis are not implemented as a "string" that is deserialized, modified, serialized and stored again (which would be not performant and use more memory), but as a highly optimized structure. To gain the performance and small memory print Redis provides, there is this "tradeoff" that a delete operation isnt always O(N), but O(N*M).

Comment: My view is: every redis object has a refcount attribute,when a key is del,the value object's refcount  minus 1, then when refcount is 0,the value memory will auto be released. are you sure redis needs to delete everything within that list as well ? and from redis source code, I didn't find  the operation of del everything within that list . thank you !

Comment: I'm sorry. when I continue read redis source code, I realized that, when a list key is del, Redis indeed needs to delete everything within that list as well .  It`s right, thank you very much !